# Chart doesn't display when data in the chart is zero

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm currently implementing a doughnut chart and I'm running into a problem.

If the data in the doughnut chart is 0, the chart does not display.

Is there an alternative to setting the data to -1?

We're currently showing the chart with the data set to -1 because the chart doesn't show when the data is 0.

Comment: If the data is 0, not clear to me the expectation. How would the chart look like if data is 0?